# Tableau: How to get number of years from number of months?

Tags: tableau-api, avmutableaudiomixinputparameters

I am trying to get the number of years of tenure from the number of Tenure months in Tableau with a function? can someone help me?
Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mw19P.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the number of years and number of months, you can create a new calculated field using the below

```
STR(INT([Tenure Months]/12)) +' Years '+ Str([Tenure Months]%12) + ' Months'
```

If you just need the number of years in float, you can create a new calculated field using the below

```
[Tenure Months]/12
```

Comment: Thank you so much Pubudu. You were amazingly helpful!